# Reopen the «How is angular momentum measured in experiments/in practice?» topic

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Moderators @Qmechanic and @dmckee marked it as a duplicate, but it is not so (see [How is angular momentum measured in experiments/in practice?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32498/how-is-angular-momentum-measured-in-experiments-in-practice#comment268412_32498) ). Linked questions are restricted to **fundamental** particles, whereas angular momentum is a concept applicable to any system. I now can’t post an answer about composite particles (currently at [How does one experimentally determine chirality, helicity, spin and angular momentum of a fundamental particle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/how-does-one-experimentally-determine-chirality-helicity-spin-and-angular-mome/131711) ) into *correct* thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think the marked duplicates cover well enough the intent of [the question you mentioned](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32498/how-is-angular-momentum-measured-in-experiments-in-practice). They are indeed slightly more focused, but there's nothing in the closed one to indicate the level of generality that's being requested. Opening it up because it sort-of also covers composite particles would mean that the question really asked 'how is angular momentum measured in *every* conceivable experimental system', and that is really much too broad.

If you have a good answer and you want to find a good home for it, you should note that **it is perfectly OK to ask a question and answer it**. In fact, many of our best questions were written this way, because this gets past the fact that the questioner often doesn't know enough about the topic to ask the really interesting questions. For some samples see the ≲1k results in [Self answers that were self-answered from the start](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/revision/219610/287619/self-answers-that-were-self-answered-from-the-start).

Comment: I pay little attention to points and badges. Please, reopen the question; then I’ll fix the mess with off-topic. If the question will not be reopened, then I’ll just drop it.

Comment: It is not up to me to reopen the question - that requires a consensus of five people or a moderator. I do disagree that it should be reopened because it is not particularly clear and does not add anything new that's not covered in the other two questions. On the other hand, your answer does contain some interesting material (though to be honest it could do with a good bit of work to clarify its main points), and in the interest of having good content on the site (and not with regard to points and badges) I would encourage you to frame it in an appropriate question.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I believe you can edit it now, which will raise a reopen flag.